# Not able to upload camera captured image on server in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on an app in which I want to get image from gallery or camera and then send it to server using multipart. I am able to send picture from gallery to server but when I tried to send image from camera it shows me failure.

// code for the same

// code fro open camera

```
     private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

}
```

// on activity result

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

                    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

            Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult: "+Uri.fromFile(destination));

       FileOutputStream fo;
            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            filePath = destination.toString();
            if (filePath != null) {

                try {
                    execMultipartPost();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image not capturd!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

// send to server code

```
  private void execMultipartPost() throws Exception {

    File file = new File(filePath);
    String contentType = file.toURL().openConnection().getContentType();

    Log.d("TAG", "file new path: " + file.getPath());
    Log.d("TAG", "contentType: " + contentType);


    RequestBody fileBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), file);

    final String filename = "file_" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;



    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)


            .addFormDataPart("date", "21-09-2017")
            .addFormDataPart("time", "11.56")
            .addFormDataPart("description", "hello")
            .addFormDataPart("image", filename + ".jpg", fileBody)


            .build();

    Log.d("TAG", "execMultipartPost: "+requestBody);

    okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
            .url("http://myexample/api/user/lets_send")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();


    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "nah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        Log.d("TAG", "response of image: " + response.body().string());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

// I  am getting onFailure executed while try to upload image from camera.

```
    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
```

Comment: post error log..!!

Comment: If you think your code is right, you should check whether your server allows uploads, also check if there is any upload file size limitation (Also check file extensions allowed by server ). I went through the same error, later found out it was a server file size limitation.

Comment: I am able to upload image using gallery but not with camera @AswinPAshok

Comment: what does `Log.d("TAG", "response of image: " + response.body().string());` this line log? Please post it

Comment: you should not get image from intent data, as it is only a micro sized preview. Specify file save path instead, and load image from file after picture is taken

Comment: Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "nah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        it is going under this code. @AswinPAshok

Comment: getting path of image captured from camera is : /storage/emulated/0/1505973955392.jpg 
And path of image from gallery :
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170921_102831.jpg . @VladMatvienko

Comment: that is not correct. Check my comment once again.

Comment: Try printing that exception. Add `Log.d("TAG",e.printStackTrace());`in onFailure method

Comment: Not an answer, but camera intent can cause exception from device to device, So i suggest using [TedBottomPicker Library](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedBottomPicker) (It handles both camera and gallery)

Comment: You are not writing `bytes` to file. Nor ceating a file. So there is no file. You could have checked that with File:exists().

Comment: what @greenapps just said is right. Please check the file location, you may find files with 0 bytes size

Comment: I am getting file not found exception. Please tell how I am able to do that

Comment: `am getting file not found exception`. When? Where? Already using File.exists() before uploading?

Comment: `you may find files with 0 bytes size ` No not even that. There will not be files as nothing is created or written.

Comment: okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
at this line

Comment: That's normal as that file does not exist. So check if the file exists before you call that statement. And don't call that statement if the file does not exist.

Comment: `execMultipartPost()`. You should change that to `execMultipartPost(filePath)`.  Use a parameter to tell the file name and path to that function.

Comment: I have almost everything but not able to do. Please help. How can I be able to make file exist. See my updated code

Comment: Have you checked out that library I mentioned? It will help you for sure

Comment: Do away with ByteArrayOutputStream bytes and use thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fo); directly.

Comment: If there is a catch then return. Do not call execMultipartPost() then. Instead display a toast so the user knows about the exception.

Comment: `destination.createNewFile();`. Do not create a file already. The new FileOutputStream will do that.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments :

Get image from gallery or camera like this :

```
File mainFile = null;
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

String partFilename = currentDateFormat();
mainFile = storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(bitmap, partFilename);



public String currentDateFormat() {
    String currentTimeStamp = null;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH_mm_ss");
        currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return currentTimeStamp;
}

public File storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(Bitmap bitmap, String currentDate) {
    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "photo_" + currentDate + ".jpg");
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outputFile;
}
```

Use **mainFile** to send in **RequestBody** and pass like **execMultipartPost(File file)**